# Updating TextView In One Function

Tags: java, android, textview, handler

I want to do something very simple. I have a progress-bar and a textView that I want to dynamically update on a button click, but more than once during the function call.

I want it to change to 'A' then wait a second, then switch to 'B' ... for example.

I understand that my function blocks the UI/main thread, which is what if I setText() ten times, I only see the tenth text appear when the function completes.

So I've tried handlers/runnables in the UI thread, invalidating (and postInvalidating) to encourage refreshing and runOnUiThread() and they all just update when they've finished running leaving me only with the final state.

```
public void requestPoint(View v) {
    textProgress.setText("Requesting A Point");
    waiting(200);
    progressBar.setProgress(5);
    textProgress.setText("Request Received!");
    waiting(500);
    ....
}
```

I think I've turned nearly all the similar question links purple and wasted way too much time on this simple thing (although I did learn a lot about threading on Android) but I feel I must be missing something crucial, this doesn't seem like that hard of task.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How on earth can `waiting()` wait without blocking the current thread?

Comment: It does my bad. Waiting just wastes time with a loop

Comment: Have you tried using a timer or an asyncTask?

Comment: I could get it to work with postDelayed() and have it increment a number every second and update. But I was having trouble passing in custom strings for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you really do just want to waste time with your waiting method. This is assuming a 200ms delay followed by a 500ms delay like in your example.

```
public void requestPoint(View v) {
    textProgress.setText("Requesting A Point");
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){ 
            progressBar.setProgress(5);
            textProgress.setText("Request Received!");
        }
    }, 200);

    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){ 
            ....
        }
    }, 700);
....
}
```

Comment: It works! I tried doing the same thing but with a re-usable runnable that wrote from public variables and then set them to the next thing but to no avail. 

Thanks for helping me, I spent way too much time trying different things before having it work.

Comment: Also, for future readers, there is a typo:
postDelayed(Runnable, int) not postDelayed(int, Runnable)